# convert integer to string then back to integer

Tags: python-3.x

I'm doing this python exercise where the goal is for a user to key in an integer and the function should be able to re-arrange (descending) I decided to convert the integer first to a string so I can iterate from that and the result is stored in a list. But when i try to convert it back to integer it doesn't get converted.

as shown in my code below, i tried printing the type of my variables so that I would see if its getting converted.

```
def conversion(nums):


    int_to_str = str(nums) 
    list_int = []
    ans = []

    for x in int_to_str: 
        list_int.append(x)


    list_int.sort(reverse=True)   

    ans = list_int          
    print (type(ans))
    print(ans)
    ans = ''.join(list_int) 
    print(type(ans))
    print(ans)



    str_to_int = [int(x) for x in list_int]  # LIST COMPREHENSION to convert 
                                             # string back to integer type 
    print(type(str_to_int))
    print(str_to_int)

    final = ''.join(str_to_int)
    print(type(final))
    print(final)
```

```
    enter code here

    <class 'list'>
    ['9', '5', '4', '2', '1', '0']
    <class 'str'>
    954210
    <class 'list'>
    [9, 5, 4, 2, 1, 0]


    TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

Comment: am sorry but this is confusing, are u asking for a function that reverses an integer input? i.e. `input: 123` --> `output: 321`?

Answer (score 1):

if I understood your question, you are receiving an input (assuming string representation of some int) and you want to convert that input to a list of integers then reverse sort and return. if that is the case:

```
def reverse_numeric_input(x):
    try:
        if type(x) != str:
            x=str(x)
        lst=[int(i) for i in x]
        lst.sort(reverse=True)
        return "".join([str(i) for i in lst])
    except Exception as e:
        print("%s error coverting ur input caused by: %s" % (e.__class__.__name__, str(e)))
```

the problem in the code you posted lies in this line `final = ''.join(str_to_int)` when you call `join`, the joined items must be cast to `str()` first. hope that helps.